# Create widget with if query

Tags: flutter, widget

When the function named GetCategorybyUser returns empty, I want only a text to appear on the page instead of the listview and say that the screen is blank, but I couldn't help it.

```
    //GetCategoryByUser Method if result is null or empty

   List<Category> GetCategorybyUser(User user) {
   List<Category> categoriesbyUser=[];

   for( var item in categories)
     {
       if(item.user.userName==user.userName)
         {
           categoriesbyUser.add(item);
         }

     }
   

    return categoriesbyUser;
 }


}
 //MyWdiget  I want to create Text instead of this widget

    Expanded(child: ListView.separated(itemBuilder: (context,index) {
              String categoryname="Henüz kategori oluşturulmamış";
 //if Query
              if (categoryRepository.GetCategorybyUser(widget.user)!=null) {
                categoryname=categoryRepository.GetCategorybyUser(widget.user)[index].categoryname;
                count=categoryRepository.GetCategorybyUser(widget.user).length;
                print("$categoryname");

                return  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("$categoryname"));
              }
              else
                {
                  return  Text("$categoryname");
                }

            }, separatorBuilder: (context,index)=>Divider(), itemCount: count)

            ),
```

Comment: use ? instead if

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Use ***Conditional Expressions*** like this:

```
Widget _showList() {
   List<Category> categories = categoryRepository.GetCategorybyUser(widget.user);
   String categoryname = "Henüz kategori oluşturulmamış";

   return Expanded(
     child: categories.isEmpty
         ? Center(child: Text(categoryname))
         : ListView.separated(
             itemCount: categories.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) => ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: () {}, child: Text("$categoryname")),
             separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
           ),
   );}
```

Notice that `GetCategorybyUser()` never returns null, because you initialized return list by this code:

```
List<Category> categoriesbyUser=[];
```

For read more information about ***Conditional Expressions*** go [Dart doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions).

I hope this useful for you.